# What is 'autogenous pressure'?

Tags: physical-chemistry, synthesis

> *Compound 1 was hydrothermally synthesized under autogenous pressure*<sup>[1]</sup>

I've seen this term used a few times, but with no real explanation of what it means forthcoming. I suspect it refers to the synthesis being performed at equilibrium pressure inside a sealed container (the aforementioned synthesis is performed in an autoclave at 160 C). Is my intuition correct?

**[1]** Sun, et al., CrystEngComm, **(2012)**, 14, 3982-3988

Comment: Well, my greek/latin intuition is confirmed by Merriam-Webster: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/autogenous But that doesn't mean chemists/engineers use it with the exact same meaning... Interesting.

Comment: @CHM - based off definition 3, I think we can conclude that the autoclave does not require a meal of blood to operate. I hope.

Comment: Could the term mean that pressure is not controlled? The autoclave is sealed and heated and the pressure comes from the heating???

Comment: @RichardTerrett HA! I didn't even read those definitions, went straight for the greek!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Autogenous pressure* synthesis is a form of [solvothermal synthesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvothermal_synthesis) (also known as [“hydrothermal synthesis”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrothermal_synthesis) if the solvent is water). In most publications I could find, the two terms (“autogenous pressure” and “—thermal synthesis”) are used together, making it clear what it is: you seal your solution in a stainless steel autoclave, and heat it up. The pressure thus generated is called *[autogenous pressure](http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/kjemi/KJM5100/h07/undervisningsmateriale/15KJM5100_2007_solvothermal_a.pdf)* because you don't apply it externally, but it simply derives from the closed nature of the container and the $(\rho,P,T)$ relationship for the fluid (its equation of state).